# Error: 'Invalid Character in Idnetifier' when trying to solve ODE's in python

Tags: python, syntax-error

In the picture below you can see the code I am trying to execute to solve an ODE but I get an error and I do not know how to fix it. I am new to programming and am learning now how to code in python to solve ODEs. The code is from this material: http://geofhagopian.net/m2c/M2C-S18/euler_method.pdf

[Click me to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnmCZ.png)

After a suggestion, here is the code written:

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x0 = float(0)
y0 = float(1)
xf = float(10)
n = float(101)
deltax=(xf−x0)/(n−1);

x = np.linspace(x0,xf,n)

y = np.zeros([n]);
y[0] = y0;
for i in range(1,n):
y[i] = deltax∗(−y[i−1]+np.sin(x[i−1])) + y[i−1]

for i in range(n):
print  x[i], y[i])



plt.plot( x , y , ’ o ’ )
plt.xlabel(” Value of x ” )
plt.ylabel(” Value of y ” )
plt.title(”Approximate Solution with Forward Euler’s Method ” )
plt.show()
```

enter code here

Comment: You probably have some character in the text that isn't what it appears: that zero might be some other Unicode character that just looks like a zero.  If you had actually *included your code as text*, we could probably tell what it is.  A screenshot is utterly useless for debugging problems like this (and most other problems involving the source code, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your quotation marks, they are in a different font. Python can't identify it, so it gave you an error.

There were also a few other things wrong with your code, such as `n` being a float.

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x0 = float(0)
y0 = float(1)
xf = float(10)
n = float(101)

deltax = (xf-x0)/(n-1)

x = np.linspace(int(x0), int(xf), int(n))

y = np.zeros([int(n)]);
y[0] = y0;
for i in range(1, int(n)):
    
    y[i] = deltax * (-y[i-1] + np.sin(x[i-1])) + y[i-1]

for i in range(int(n)):
    print(x[i], y[i])



plt.plot( x , y , "o")
plt.xlabel("Value of x")
plt.ylabel("Value of y")
plt.title("Approximate Solution with Forward Euler’s Method")
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps!